# [Spring-boot, restTemplate]JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type XXXX from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: json, spring-boot

I use Spring-boot and RestTemplate.
I'm having trouble translating from json to Dto.

Client

```
Items items = restTemplate.getForObject("https://xxxxx/xxxxx, Items.class);
```

Items

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class Items {

    private List<Item> Items;

    public Items() {
        Items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(Items.size());
    }
}
```

Item

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item {

    private String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" + "title=" + title + '}';
    }

}
```

### Json is here(formatted).

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Item": {
        "limitedFlag": 0,
        "authorKana": "XXX",
        "author": "XXX",
        "subTitle": "XXX",
        "seriesNameKana": "XXXX",
        "title": "XXXX",
        "subTitleKana": "XXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "Item": {
        "limitedFlag": 0,
        "authorKana": "XXX",
        "author": "XXX",
        "subTitle": "XXX",
        "seriesNameKana": "XXXX",
        "title": "XXXX",
        "subTitleKana": "XXXX"
      }
    }
  ],
  "last": 30
}
```

---

I receive this error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ldev.itboot.mb.rest.Item;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ldev.itboot.mb.rest.Item;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

I looked here and on google but still cannot figure out.

Any response would be helpful.

Regards.

Comment: Check the json with https://jsonformatter.org/ , there is some error inside

Comment: @ samabcde Thank you for your adivice.As you mentioned, json was wrong.Now I reviced.

Answer (score 1):

The end of your JSON seem incorrect, there should be a comma after the array, before "last".

```
  ]
  "last": 30
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, my check was lax. Now it is correct.